# Graying out an undefined code section in Emacs

Tags: c++, c, emacs, syntax-highlighting

How can I gray out an undefined section of C/C++ code, example:

```
#if 0
// this section should be grayed out.
#else
// this section should be syntax-colored as usual.
#endif
```